# UITableView 'Bookmark'

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with sections.  There's a lot of data in it so there's a lot of scrolling.  When I leave the page(viewWillDisappear) I want to be able to 'bookmark' the current top visible section so the user can come back to that section they left off at when they return to the view.  I am using scrollToRowAtIndexPath to get there when the view loads but **I cannot figure out how to get the index (or position or what?) of the current top visible section** when they leave the view (without using didSelectRowAtIndexPath) so I can save it and use it with scrollToRowAtIndexPath when returning.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` which has the defined:

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated;
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint contentOffset;
```

You should be able to use these on the `UITableView` instance.